Not executing kernel even though bootloader is working properly
I am trying to build a simple bootloader and a kernel. The bootloader is at 0x7C00 and the kernel is at 0x1000. The kernel is never being executed even though the jmp is to the correct location. The bootloader is working correctly.
boot.asm
[BITS 16]       ; We are in real mode (16-bit)
[ORG 0x7C00]        ; Origin of the bootloader (BIOS loads it at 0x7C00)

start:
    xor ax, ax  ; Clear AX register (AX = 0)
    mov ds, ax  ; set DS to 0x0000 (needed for some instructions)

    ; Print bootloader message
    mov si, bootloader_msg  ; Load address of bootloader message
    call print_string   ; call the print string function

    ; Load the kernel into memory
    mov ax, 0x1000  ; Load kernel at memory segment 0x1000
    mov es, ax  ; set ES to 0x1000, this is used by the interupt 0x13 to read the sector later
    mov bx, 0x0000  ; Offset 0 in the segment

    ; Read 1 sector (512 bytes) from the disk into the memory (kernel sector)
    mov ah, 0x02    ; BIOS function: Read sectors
    mov al, 1   ; Read 1 (increase this number to read multiple sectors) sector
    mov ch, 0   ; Cylinder/track number 0
    mov dh, 0   ; Head number 0
    mov cl,2    ; Sector number 2 (sector number 1 is bootloader)
    int 0x13    ; BIOS interupt to read disk

    jc error    ; if carry flag is set then jump to error

    ; Jump to kernel entry point
    jmp 0x1000:0000
    
    ; Print debug message
    mov si, debug_msg   ; Load address of debug message
    call print_string   ; call the print string function


error:
    mov si, error_msg   ; Load error message
    call print_string   ; Print error message
    hlt         ; Halt the CPU

print_string:
    mov ah, 0x0E
print_loop:
    lodsb
    cmp al, 0
    je done
    int 0x10
    jmp print_loop
done:
    ret

bootloader_msg db 'Loading kernel...', 0
debug_msg db 'Not jumped to kernel...', 0
error_msg db 'Error  loading Kenel...', 0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55

kernel.asm:
[BITS 16]             ; We are in real mode (16-bit)
[ORG 0x1000]         ; Origin of the kernel (should match where it is loaded)

start:
    ; Set up segment registers
    xor ax, ax        ; Clear AX register
    mov ds, ax        ; Set DS to 0x0000
    mov es, ax        ; Set ES to 0x0000

    ; Print kernel message
    mov si, kernel_msg  ; Load address of kernel message
    call print_string    ; Call the print string function

hang:
    jmp hang            ; Infinite loop to prevent exit

print_string:
    mov ah, 0x0E       ; BIOS function to write character
print_loop:
    lodsb              ; Load byte at DS:SI into AL and increment SI
    cmp al, 0          ; Check for null terminator
    je done            ; If zero, end of string
    int 0x10          ; Call BIOS to print character
    jmp print_loop     ; Repeat for next character
done:
    ret                 ; Return to caller

kernel_msg db 'Hello from the kernel!', 0  ; Message to print

; Fill the remaining space in the kernel to make it a full sector
times 512 - ($ - $$) db 0

I am using ubuntu 20.04 in wsl.
I made a .img file using the following command:
 dd if=/dev/zero of=floppy.img bs=512 count=2880
Ran the following commands:
nasm -f bin boot.asm -o boot.bin
nasm -f bin kernel.asm -o kernel.bin
cat boot.bin kernel.bin > floppy.img
qemu-system-x86_64 -drive format=raw,file=floppy.img

When checked the image file using hexdump, everything is in the correct position.
hexdump output
It prints 'Loading kernel...' but then it is just stuck and doesnot do anything.
output
I am trying to build a simple bootloader and a kernel. I was expecting 'Loading kernel...' and 'Hello from the kernel!' as output. Only 'Loading kernel...' is printed.

[ORG 0x1000] ; Origin of the kernel (should match where it is loaded) yeah well except it does not. Since you load to 1000:0000 that means org 0 (or just omit it as that is the default).

lodsb takes bytes from ds:si = 0000:001b, first line of the kernel code should be mov ax,0x1000.

Case jmp 0x0000:0x1000

The bootloader is at 0x7C00 and the kernel is at 0x1000.

From this sentence most people would immediately understand both these values are offsets. And indeed that is also what the kernel got built for (linear address 4096). But then the bootloader would need the following changed:
xor  ax, ax      ; Load kernel at memory segment 0x0000
mov  es, ax
mov  bx, 0x1000  ; Offset 4096 in the segment
...
; Jump to kernel entry point
jmp  0x0000:0x1000

Case jmp 0x1000:0x0000
If however you truly did want to load the kernel at segment 0x1000 (linear address 65536) then the changes must go to the kernel.asm:
[ORG 0x0000]
start:
push cs        ; CS == 0x1000 because of the `jmp 0x1000:0x0000`
pop  ds        ; that brought us here


It is always a good idea to include a one-time cld instruction in your bootloader so that your lodsb instruction operates in the correct direction (ascending addresses).

Hmm,  a thougt come to my mind that data segment override could be used here too. I didn't test it. mov si, cs: kernel_msg. I think this is legal instruction.

No, that didn't work but I inserted cs override prefix byte 2e before lodsb and instruction changed to lods al, byte ptr cs:[si] and this looks alright.

@Nassau As documented in the old instruction reference you can write cs lodsb in NASM to use a string operation with a segment override, which will be used instead of the default ds. (The es used by some string operations cannot be overridden.)

@ecm Great! :) My brain was in masm mode and now is in nasm mode :P This is even better.
